# Paypal In-context checkout inconsistent flow

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I followed the guideline for the in context integration. The first page looks OK:

[image]

But after that when I login, the next page I get is the regular checkout page, but inside the popup which looks weird.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZNce.png[image]

Has anyone seen this before ?